# How to get resize events on DockingPanel?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using this example to create DockingPanel:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel
Now I need to catch resize event and to resize DIV content when panel is resized.    How to do that, please? Thank you.

Comment: Could someone explain why is my question down-voted? I just want to learn what is problem with question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today the `DockingPanel` does not trigger any event when it's resized. In order to catch that event yourself, you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to intercept any changes to the `style` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for info.